# Testing for non-linear interaction in multiple regression

Tags: regression, interaction, nonlinear-regression

I have conducted an experiment and measured 3 main variables, let's call the independent variables A and B and let's call the dependent variable C. I had postulated that there will be an interaction between variable A and B. the results suggest that interaction does exists but a non-linear one. By looking at the graph, I conclude that the for the central values of variable A, the magnitude of the effect of variable B is larger. Variables A and B has a linear relationship with the variable C, the dependent variable. What I'd like to do is to test the significance of the interaction effect, but I'm not sure whether I can use linear regression, since the interaction effect is non-linear. It seems to me that the assumption of linearity is being violated because the interaction variable is non-linear. Am I correct? If so what should be my course of action?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The term "linear model" means a model that is linear in the parameters, not a model that is linear in the independent variables. So you can use a linear model for nonlinear terms in X, eg, polynomials in X or interactions of polynomials with other terms.

Comment: You are not correct, as @DavidSmith said. You can model this with multiple regression. My intuition is that you want something like `c ~ a + b + a^2 + a*b + b*a^2`, because the effect of `b` depends on the quadratic form of `a`. But I'm trying to generate data that fit the pattern you are seeing from this model and can't quite get it.